# WordPress Page Loader

Tags: jquery, wordpress, loader

I am creating a WordPress website. I want to add a page loader. The page loader works (I created it using CSS). I added a div in header. However, the page loader won't hide/disappear once the page has been fully loaded. This is causing my pages to be inactive, by that I mean I cannot click on anything on my site once it's loaded as the page loader is still on "top" of everything.

```js
// WP JQuery wrapper
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 //***** Page Loader Call ***** // 
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(.'se-pre-con').animate();
    });
 
 $(window).load(function() {
      $('#loader-wrapper").hide();
    });
  }
```

```css
#loader-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.se-pre-con {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #3498db;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}
 
.se-pre-con:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #e74c3c;
    -webkit-animation: spin 3s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
      animation: spin 3s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}
 
.se-pre-con:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #f9c922;
    -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
      animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}
 
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0%   {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* IE 9 */
        transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* IE 9 */
        transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    0%   {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* IE 9 */
        transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* IE 9 */
        transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    }
}
```

```html
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

  <div id=loader-wrapper>
   <div class="se-pre-con"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have syntax errors. Try below code in script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.se-pre-con').animate();
});

jQuery(window).load(function() {
  jQuery('#loader-wrapper').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Nilesh Yadav.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

Add the following in wp header.php

```
<div id=loader-wrapper>
        <div class="se-pre-con"></div>
</div>
```

In your css file

```
.hidden {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Add the following code in your footer.php or any file

```
//on page loading hide the page loader 
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("#loader-wrapper").addClass("hidden");
    });
```

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/6v7sccuf/12/